Why use Source Link with embedded symbol files (PDB)?
I was looking at the .Net Foundation Eligibility Criteria and saw this part


The project uses Source Link.
The project uses either embedded PDBs or publish symbol packages to NuGet (if applicable).


It seems this is an AND condition, so why would anyone use Source Link if you have embedded the PDBs?
As far as I know Source Link allows you to step through the code by requesting the symbol files from wherever you set it up. But that seems like a m00t point if the symbols are already embedded.
I just see no point in using both.
